# Python Output to html file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have looked all over the web with fail. I am running a python script that i want it to output data from to my html file in a table format. How can that be done since all am getting is CGI and all that which i have no idea about!

Comment: http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/pytenjin-examples.html#bordered-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453799/how-to-create-a-table-using-python

Comment: @Ess_Dablew DON'T Write pure HTML yourself, it is error prone, ugly, tiring, tedious and what not! Use templating system like jinja, mako or django.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're actually asking. Could you rephrase your question, show what you've tried so far, what you've read/RTFM and where are you blocking/what do you exactly don't understand? Otherwise, I'd just suggest you to buy a python introduction book…

Comment: Am reading files from a database and displaying them on a table. The data is not static and that is why am seeing editing it as just a file wont work well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An HTML file is just a normal file.

```
with open("/tmp/myfile.html", "w") as my_file:
  my_file.write("<html><body><table>")
  for x in range(5):
    my_file.write("<tr><td>%d</td></tr>" % x)
  my_file.write("</table></body></html>")
```